# Select rows matching date bundaries and last 'rent' book before these dates

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, mysql-8.0

There are libraries. Every library have plenty of books. And each book may have many statuses (`rent`, `available`, `unavailable`).

I want to get all books that were `rent` in 2020.

So I have to select all of the books that had status `rent` with status date between `2020-01-01` and `2021-01-01` AND (and thats the hard part) books that have their last status before 2020-01-01 set to `rent`.

I have no idea how to achieve that.

---

Libraries:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | We have no books |
| 2 | We have books |

Books table:

| id | library_id | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | The title |
| 2 | 2 | Book about books |
| 3 | 1 | Stackoverflow. Best questions you don't care about. |
| 4 | 2 | Wikipedia Printed Edition |

Statuses table:

| id | book_id | status | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | available | 2019-01-20 |
| 2 | 3 | rent | 2019-11-21 |
| 3 | 3 | available | 2019-11-29 |
| 4 | 4 | available | 2019-12-01 |
| 5 | 4 | rent | 2019-12-10 |
| 6 | 2 | available | 2019-12-20 |
| 7 | 2 | rent | 2019-12-30 |
| 8 | 4 | available | 2020-01-02 |
| 9 | 1 | available | 2020-01-20 |
| 10 | 1 | rent | 2020-01-22 |
| 11 | 1 | available | 2020-01-24 |
| 12 | 2 | available | 2021-01-04 |
| 13 | 3 | rent | 2021-01-23 |

So the query I need should return all book names and libray name for all books that were rent during any part of 2020.

So the expectted result should be something like that:

| id | library | book |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | We have no books | The title |
| 2 | Book about books | We have books |
| 3 | Wikipedia Printed Edition | We have books |

- Book `1` because have `rent` status set in 2020
- Book `2` because was `rent` in 2019, and retured in 2021 (so was rent in 2020)
- Book `4` because its last status in 2019 was `rent`

Book `3` is NOT included, because its last status in 2019 was set to `available`, and was rent in 2021

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: In the first part of your select you don't care what the most recent status is , in the second part you want the last status = rent. I am not clear what you mean by And each book may have many statuses - you have 1 row per book or a row for every status change for book (which is what the question implies)?

Comment: @P.Salmon so if you can, write some working examle. I am trying since yesterday.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a centralized table of 'books' would have a 'library_id' column within it

Comment: Is id in status table really duplicated or is it an auto_increment column?

Comment: @P.Salmon my mistake when typing sample table data. Its an autoncrement field

Answer (score 1):

A simplified answer based solely on status involves capturing the last status in 2019 using a max function and a union for 2020

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int auto_increment primary key,bid int, status varchar(20), dt date);
insert t(bid,status,dt) values
(3  ,'available',   '2019-01-20'),
(3  ,'rent'    ,  '2019-11-21'),
(3  ,'available',   '2019-11-29'),
(4  ,'available',   '2019-12-01'),
(4  ,'rent'    ,  '2019-12-10'),
(2  ,'available',   '2019-12-20'),
(2  ,'rent'    ,   '2019-12-30'),
(4  ,'available',   '2020-01-02'),
(1  ,'available',   '2020-01-20'),
(1  ,'rent'    ,  '2020-01-22'),
(1  ,'available',   '2020-01-24'),
(2  ,'available',   '2021-01-04'),
(3  ,'rent'    ,  '2021-01-23');

select * from
(
select  t.bid, t.status 
from t
where  (t.status = 'rent' and dt between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31') 
limit 1
) a
union  all
select  t.bid ,t.status
from t  
join (select  bid ,max(id) id from t where dt < '2020-01-01' group by bid) s
      on s.bid = t.bid and t.id = s.id 
having status = 'rent'
;

+------+--------+
| bid  | status |
+------+--------+
|    1 | rent   |
|    4 | rent   |
|    2 | rent   |
+------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.022 sec)
```

Comment: And bang, I forgot about unions. Thanks for that. But the problem is that the source dataset is veeery large. So this query wont handle it in rational time. But thank you for solving my problem that way

Comment: As long as you have indexes in place then the query should perform ok. How many rows is very large? Have you tested or assumed?

Comment: yup, I used that. For small set it works fine, but dev DB contains about 10mln book records, what causes some problems ;-) Production table will contain something line 10x more records.

Comment: OK now it's a performance problem - test both parts of union separately , tell me what indexes are in place on the table, run explain plan against the query and analyse result,